# Rules event is not triggering

Tags: commerce, rules, actions

I've created a custom action to fire when the "checkout is complete" event occurs. The front end is a mobile application, where as the back end is Drupal. So I create an order using its API and update the status the of the order to "complete" manually. But the event is not triggering.

Do anyone know what I'm doing wrong? When I've changed the event to when an order is created, the action is performing.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Since this site is about Drupal, there isn't any need to put _Drupal_ in the title; it is implicit the question is about Drupal, or it would be off-topic.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Really, that was the answer I was looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Change the status to "complete" manually may not trigger the rule. Instead, applying a payment for the order manually may work.
[See here](https://drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/checkout-completion-rules)